# How to get scraped data from MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to get scraped urls, stocked in a mongo db, to my scrapy spider and 
then iterate on it with Selenium.

Everything goes well with this code, I just want to iterate on "urls" I've scraped and stocked in mongodb. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path')
driver.get('https://www.website.com')

#login page
email = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
email.send_keys('email@gmail.com')
sleep(0.5)

password  = driver.find_element_by_name('pass')
password.send_keys('mypass')
sleep(0.5)

sign_in_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@type="button"]')
sign_in_button.click()
sleep(5)

#pre-home
next_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2pii')
next_button.click()
sleep(5)

#pages to scrape
urls = ('https://www.website.com/page1','https://www.website.com/page2')

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(5)

    try:
        add_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_5caa", " " ))]')
        add_button.click()

    except:
        pass
```

Comment: so basically, this is the question about how to get data from mongodb and has nothing to do with selenium.